# It doesn't matter the side you see it

Tags: riddle

> It doesn't matter the side you see it,
>
> As long as it's vertical, it's still the same,
>
> Just be sure that at night,
>
> you know where to aim.

What is it?

Comment: -1 Your accepted answer does not fit your clues.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer is

> This urinal, obviously.
>  [image: A large restroom somewhere]

Ok, yes, I know ....

Comment: *Just be sure that at night, you know where to aim.* -> Perfect answer

Comment: Ha! I like it, I was thinking along the same lines but couldn't find a proper one that shape.

Comment: I cannot imagine how the expected answer can beat this one.

Comment: Your picture is a circular wash fountain and is used to wash your hands.  It is NOT supposed to be used for the purpose you imply, so it loses on the last line of the clue.  https://www.bradleycorp.com/product/54-stainless-steel-circular-classic-washfountain

Comment: @Keeta at the risk of repeating myself:  "Ok, yes, I know ..."

Comment: @Rubio: I Assume that was aimed at the asker as much as at you... They have accepted this as the right answer...

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> A guardsman patrolling a perimeter wall

It doesn’t matter the side you see it

> It doesn’t matter which side of the wall he’s patrolling

As long as it’s vertical it’s still the same

> He’s watchful unless he lies down to take a nap

Just be sure when at night, you know where to aim

> So to break out/break in, you have to get rid of him: aim and shoot him off the wall.